# SSRS Group By Data in Row but Vertically

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have a problem to produce a SSRS report that is like this:
[image]

This is how my output from stored procedure looks like:

```
Company Code | Company Name | Product Code | Product Name
   ICE001    |    Nestle    |    ICE001a   |  Drumstick Chocolate    
   ICE001    |    Nestle    |    ICE001b   |  Drumstick KitKat 
   ICE001    |    Nestle    |    ICE001c   |  Drumstick Chocolate
   ICE002    |    Walls     |    ICE002a   |  Cornetto Chocolate 
   ICE002    |    Walls     |    ICE002b   |  Cornetto Latte 
   ICE002    |    Walls     |    ICE002c   |  Cornetto La Liga
```

So how can I achieve this report structure in SSRS with the current stored procedure? Is it achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, yes you can. These are the steps:

1. Drag a table into the SSRS.
2. Make it 2 columns and 1 row.
3. On the first column, select the field you want as the sub data which in this case, Product Code.
4. In 2nd column, put in Product Name.
5. Now for the main data. Right click on the first column, select:
   *Insert Row > Outside Group - Above*
6. Put the main data field which is Company Code at the first row, first column.
7. Put the Company Name expression at the second column, first row of the table.
8. Design as your preferred and generate your report :)

Answer (score 0):

Doubt it. But if you adjust your dataset as below and use a table report it is.

```
select distinct code,company from icecream 
union
select productcode,productname from icecream
```